# button drag and drop

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to use one button drag and drop functionality to my application.
My requirement I have one view called ViewA and there is one button in it.
That should be able to drag and drop it into the another view called ViewB.
How do I do that?. When I search over the internet I got some examples. But those examples display only text drag and drop. For that they use TextTransfer. In this case, what should I use? Also I found one GadgetTransfer. Can that be used for my example?But when I use GadgetTransfer, I got compilation error. How do I ressolve that?
From the following site only I got the example. Please see below.

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Workbench-DND/drag_drop.html

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the compilation error that you received.

Comment: The thing is, when I tried to use GadgetTransfer, it did not ressolve.Later I found out that the GadgetTransfer class they have created only for that example. so it is not a generic class. Which is the transfer class I can use for Button drag and drop?

Comment: `GadgetTransfer` is just a sample implementation of a `Transfer` - there is no 'default' transfer for dragging buttons; you'll have to create your own.